# "Verification failed" when trying to update to iOS 8.1.1 because of a network issue

Tags: software-update, ios

I have an iPhone 5s and whenever I try to update it to iOS 8.1.1 it shows the error message below:

> iOS 8.1.1 failed verification because you are no longer connected to the internet.

However, I'm connected to the internet. I tried with 2 Wi-Fi connections.
Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: Have you restarted your phone?

Comment: Do it on iTunes, download separately, then update.

Answer (score -1):

You phone Charge must be more then 50%